# No module named "SSUtilities" within Optimized Hot Spot Analysis tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, syntaxerror

**Background**

I'm trying to execute Optimized Hot Spot Analysis tool in ArcGIS 10.3 but receive the following error:

[image: ArcMap Error]

**Additional Information**

I've had a look at some other tools within the same toolbox and have noticed I'm also missing the "WeightsUtilities" module within the Cluster and Outlier Analysis tool. In this particular question, I am only interested in finding the "SSUtilities" module, but it would be grand if the method used to find it can be applied to other modules which may be missing in the future.

**Question**

Where and how can I find the missing "SSUtilities" module needed within the Optimized Hot Spot Analysis tool?

Comment: This sounds like a problem for the ESRI support. Have you contacted them?

Comment: @BERA I haven't actually - thought I'd try here first! Not in any major rush at the moment so if I've had no luck by the end of the day, I'll try ESRI.